# Why is my code not getting me to input in this loop? It doesn't read it

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

So I am trying to make a tic tack toe game and ive done the board fine but when creating a loop def I've asked for input but when I run it, I'm never prompted to input my move

```
board = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "X", "6"], ["7", "8", "9"]]

def display_board(board):
    print("+-------+-------+-------+")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("|   " + board[0][0] + "   |   " + board[0][1] + "   |   " + board[0][2] + "   |")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("+-------+-------+-------+")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("|   " + board[1][0] + "   |   " + board[1][1] + "   |   " + board[1][2] + "   |")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("+-------+-------+-------+")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("|   " + board[2][0] + "   |   " + board[2][1] + "   |   " + board[2][2] + "   |")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("+-------+-------+-------+")

def enter_move(board):

    while True:

        move = int(input("Please pick a number within the range of squares (1-9): "))

        if move < 1 or move > 9:
            print("Error please pick a number 1 through 9: ")
            continue
        elif move not in [0] and move not in [1] and move not in [2]:
            print("Sorry please try another move that square is already taken!")
            continue
        elif move == 1:
            board[0][0] == "O"
        elif move == 2:
            board[0][1] == "O"
        elif move == 3:
            board[0][2] == "O"
        elif move == 4:
            board[1][0] == "O"
        elif move == 6:
            board[1][2] == "O"
        elif move == 7:
            board[2][0] == "O"
        elif move == 8:
            board[2][1] == "O"
        elif move == 9:
            board[2][2] == "O"

        break
```

im expecting it for me to input an integer when I click run but nothing happens

Comment: Do you actually call the `enter_move()` function anywhere in your code?  It was pointless to define it, otherwise.

Comment: also in your `enter_move()` you are not calling anywhere `display_board()`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called the `enter_move()` function in your code. Write this at the end of your code!

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    enter_move(board)
```

Or you can directly use `while` loop with out calling `enter_move()` function like:

```
board = [["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "X", "6"], ["7", "8", "9"]]


def display_board(board):
    print("+-------+-------+-------+")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("|   " + board[0][0] + "   |   " + board[0][1] + "   |   " + board[0][2] + "   |")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("+-------+-------+-------+")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("|   " + board[1][0] + "   |   " + board[1][1] + "   |   " + board[1][2] + "   |")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("+-------+-------+-------+")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("|   " + board[2][0] + "   |   " + board[2][1] + "   |   " + board[2][2] + "   |")
    print("|       |       |       |")
    print("+-------+-------+-------+")


while True:

    move = int(input("Please pick a number within the range of squares (1-9): "))

    if move < 1 or move > 9:
        print("Error please pick a number 1 through 9: ")
        continue
    elif move not in [0] and move not in [1] and move not in [2]:
        print("Sorry please try another move that square is already taken!")
        continue
    elif move == 1:
        board[0][0] == "O"
    elif move == 2:
        board[0][1] == "O"
    elif move == 3:
        board[0][2] == "O"
    elif move == 4:
        board[1][0] == "O"
    elif move == 6:
        board[1][2] == "O"
    elif move == 7:
        board[2][0] == "O"
    elif move == 8:
        board[2][1] == "O"
    elif move == 9:
        board[2][2] == "O"

    break
```

Comment: `enter_move` required one parameter also..!

Comment: oops yeah silly brain, thank you!

Comment: you run the first code is it working..! i don't think so cause you have not given any parameter in `enter_move()`.. @Apne Duniya

Comment: @YashMehta no need as it is taking input already!

Comment: don't get it what you are trying to say can you be more brief..! @ApneDuniya

Comment: `move = int(input("Please pick a number within the range of squares (1-9): "))` will take input so no need for parameter in `enter_move()`

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__":
    enter_move()`  Write this at the end of your code!.. This will give an error `enter_move() missing 1 required positional argument: 'board'` @ApneDuniya